# Error creating sessionFactory in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Code is throwing exception while creating session factory when I am using below mapping.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 
3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 6 Apr, 2017 8:48:54 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.5.0.Final -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.users.Users" table="USERS">
    <id name="id" type="int">
        <column name="ID" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="NAME" />
    </property>

    <component name="UsersData" class ="com.users.UsersData">
        <property name="age" type="int">
            <column name="age" />
        </property>
    </component>


</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

However, it works fine when I remove the code containing component mapping.

I have created Users and UsersData class and used UsersData class in Users class.

Comment: Can you please tell me which method you are using to save the values?

Comment: I am using setters in the Users class to save the value

Comment: No, I mean save/persist/saveOrUpdate/update/merge?